# Why does the find command not seem to work with sharelatex files?

Tags: editors, sharelatex

In Safari (and also Chrome, it seems) my attempts to search for a word in a sharelatex file, does not in general succeed, as it always seems to do on other web pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShareLaTex support wrote me: "We do have an inbuilt search feature in the ShareLaTeX editor which should provide better functionality. Just click into the editor and press 'Ctrl + F' ('CMD + F on Mac)."

This seems to work.